# IllegalStateException on sign to Google api client

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use sign-in mode: SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL. Mode was already set to SIGN_IN_MODE_NONE
```

What does this mean? How to prevent it?

The suggestion in other similar SO question was

```
 mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
```

But I have been using this itself.

Here is the onActivityResult

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
        authInProgress = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting() && !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                googleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
            } else {
                onConnected(null);
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            startApiClientConnect();
        }
    } else {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        startApiClientConnect();
    }
}
```

After the initial connection attempt if it was not successful then the `googleApiClient.connect` is reattempted in the `onActivityResult`. I believe this is reattempt is causing the problem. After initial connection failure / some user action makes the SIGN_IN_MODE_NONE.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not allowed to provide a sign in mode to the connect(int) method more than once. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect(int)) says "It is an error to make multiple calls to this method passing different modes. Once a mode is selected, all future connect calls must use the same mode." So it might be that you're calling `connect()` with differing arguments. `SIGN_IN_MODE_NONE` doesn't seems to be an option for the parameter, so I think you're calling `connect()` in one case and `connect(int)` in another (with `SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL`). Check that out and see if you can make them consistent.

Also, I believe callbacks for GoogleApiClient are `onConnected(Bundle)` and `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)`

Comment: seems like a plausible reason. But here is a statement for `public void connect (int signInMode)`. 

According to documentation: It is an error to make multiple calls to this method passing different modes. Once a mode is selected, all future connect calls must use the same mode.

How did the mode change to `SIGN_IN_MODE_NONE` then.

Comment: I think it's because you're calling `public void connect()` before `public void connect(int)` since `SIGN_IN_MODE_NONE` is not an option as a parameter. Look for that and choose either mode none or mode optional.

I'm guessing the other SO post you're referring to is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063607/google-signin-not-working). I'm not sure if you're trying to login like him, but for my login I put this in my `onConnectionFailedListener`: `result.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_LOGIN);` That popped up the login dialog

Comment: Yes I was referring to that SO question. I did have `result.startResolutionForResult` but was still getting this error. Unfortunately the error was never reproducible at my end but the crash reports sent from clients showed it. I have tried, re-registering the callbacks and then again `googleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL)`. I haven't received any crash report yet, but it is early days. Can't confirm how this prevents the issue.

Comment: by the way, I am always using `googleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);` throughout the code. I also have registered `OnConnectionFailedListener` and `ConnectionCallbacks`.

Comment: So it's not a problem anymore?